# How do I style the Plot Bands for a graph in a telerik report using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, graph, kendo-ui, telerik, reporting

I have recently been brought on to a project that uses Kendo UI controls and Telerik Reporting reports to display various charts and graphs.

There is an existing Kendo UI Chart widget that displays a student's 'score' across the months of current and past school years. The score ranges from 0 to 100. The Y-Axis represents the 'score' and the X-Axis represents the School Year/Month.

In addition, the 0 to 100 scale of the Y-Axis is broken down into rankings: 65-70 = poor, 71 - 80 = fair, etc.  This ranking is displayed via different colored Plot Bands on the Y-Axis in the Kendo UI Chart.  The Plot Bands are configured using custom C# code to establish the To, From, Color and Opacity properties of each Plot band for the value series.

Here is the code:

```
var thresholds= _[*entity framework call to generate database driven values*];
List<PlotBand> plotBands = new List<PlotBand>();
foreach (var threshold in thresholds)
{
    plotBands.Add(new PlotBand() 
    { 
        From = threshold.Min, 
        To = threshold.Max, 
        Color = threshold.RiskColor.ColorCode, 
        Opacity = .3 
    });
}
```

This works as expected and generates a Kendo UI Chart that appears like this:

[kendo ui chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBITr.png)

I have been asked to duplicate the chart in a Telerik Reporting report. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Pro and designing the report from inside VS (i.e. not using the stand alone designer) with the Telerik Reporting Q1 2015 SP1 version.

Yes, i know these are not the latest, but it's what I was given....

The Telerik Reporting Graph control and the Kendo UI Chart widgets are similar but not identical. I can re-create 90% of the chart using the graph control. The only portion missing is the color-coded ranking that displays as the background to the chart. There does not seem to be any analogous properties for the Chart's Plot Bands within the Graph control.

I've tried creating a secondary coordinate system and using multiple Cross Axis positions as described by Telerik [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/graph---are-plot-bands-possible). That allows me to create the psuedo-plot bands but not style them. I cannot find any property in the Graph control, or any of its components, that allows me to set the color or opacity for each plot band.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a very recent KB article that explains how to do that - as you've guessed, it requires an additional series and coordinate system. You can check it here: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/how-to-create-plot-bands-using-the-graph-item.

About the colour opacity: Try setting the colours using the ARGB values directly, like 128;64;64;64 - this should be a transparent grey-ish colour.